# Scan directories, find string within files and print results

Tags: string, file, loops, python-3.x, directory

The title probably does not do anyone justice so let me get right to it.
I am trying to write a program that will scan my drive `E:\` for a list of words such as `water`, `fire` and `air`. Within my `E:\` drive, I obviously have folders within folders and files within the folders, and so on.

I want to call the function `search (path, text)`, which, in text, be able to enter the list `['water', 'fire', 'air']`. So it would look like this: `search('E:\\', ['water', 'fire', 'air'])`.

I want to be able to scan the directory(ies) and with each 'line' it scans, print `Scanning: E:\\...`. I have this. I also want when it finds water, fire and/or air, to output `In (directory name) found water, fire`; `In (directory name) found air`, etc. I have most of this part. I cannot figure out how to get it to display multiple words (if applicable).

An output I am looking for would be like this, for example:

`Scanning: E:\
 Scanning: E:\Python Fun!
 Scanning: E:\Python Fun!\1st Week
 Scanning: E:\Python Fun!\2nd Week
 Scanning: E:\Python Fun!\3rd Week
 In E:\Python Fun!\3rd Week\elements.txt found 'fire', 'water'
 Scanning: E:\Python Fun!\4th Week
 Scanning: E:\Python Fun!\5th Week
 In E:\Python Fun!\5th Week\elements.txt found 'air
 Scanning...`
 And so on

Here is my code:

```
import os
def search(path, text):

    for text in texts:
        if os.path.isfile(path): #base case
            if text in path:
                print(path)
            return

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return

    for item in os.listdir(path):
        itempath = os.path.join(path, item)

        if os.path.isfile(itempath):
            if text in item:
                print('In {} found {}'.format(itempath, word))

        elif os.path.isdir(itempath):

            search(itempath, text)
            print('Scanning:', path)
            #open(itempath).read() #tested this but got an error. See below.
        else: #unknown object type
            pass

search('E:\\',['water','fire', 'air'])
```

The `Traceback` error I got was `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`. So I commented it out.

With this code, I am getting results of basically the last letter of whatever is in my list, in this case, `r` as what's being searched. I am thinking that is due to an extra loop? But not sure exactly.

I know I need to add an `open filename` somewhere but again, I am confused as to how to implement that. I just started learning about the OS module so that's where the bulk of the confusion comes into play. I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

For recursively iterating your drive consider using `glob` instead:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('E:/**/**', recursive=True):
    print("Scanning", filename);
    with open(filname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file: content = file.read()
    for text in texts:
        if text in content:
            print("Found:", text, " - ", filename);
```

In order to scan the contents of the files, you also need to `open()` them.

Comment: Would there possibly be a way to do it without glob? It will probably make the code less simple, which is anticipated. But I would like to learn the detailedness of python and then get into the shortcuts later on so I know what I am doing and what to look for when confronted by a complicated situation.